# What can I put on a wooden dowel to have a good grip?

Tags: finishing, technique

There’s a wooden dowel in which I will put ties on. Something like this:

[image]

How can I add a grip to the wooden dowels so the ties would stay on firmly?

Comment: Maybe silicone tubing slit along its length? That seems to have a pretty good grip to it, the bits I've handled at least.

Comment: This isn't a query that comes up a lot! I'll be interested to see what suggestions people come up with. My first thought was roughening the surface with sandpaper but with silk ties I'm not sure that would be practical.

Comment: Try some stick on foam. Like the stuff used around doors. I am thinking that it would be very easy to stick to the wood and then the foam should give some grip, or at least I would think. The only issue I can see with this is if the glue is not strong enough the foam will peel. So maybe you would have to put on better glue. Even hot glue I am sure would be good reinforcement. But otherwise give that a try!

Comment: @Ljk2000 That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: sharkskin baby !

Answer (score 4):

My first instinct is to try plasti-dip. You can get it in brush on or spray on. I made a wooden multi-guitar stand many years ago, and it worked great to protect the guitars and keep them from slipping at all.

[Plasti Dip](https://plastidip.com/our-products/plasti-dip/)

Comment: Came here to say that. Leaving satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

### Rubber tubing

Ever replaced a bicycle inner tube and wonder what to do with it? Or other tire tubes or a snow tube that broke? I should think that scraps of tubing would create enough friction to stop them from sliding off. You would not need to much and small scraps can be glue or have small staples hold them in place. Some inner tubes have a coating on the inside, like functioning as a sealant, so you would need to place this inside in.

Staples might not be ideal since it risks having material get caught or tear. If it is small enough and placed on the bottom of the rung, where ties wont likely touch, this might not be an issue.

Some glue from a hot glue gun would help hold it in place easy.

Rubber in general is my suggestion. It would also be easy to experiment without causing damage to the hangar.

Comment: To that, I'd add, maybe try surgical tubing. Less rubber stuff smudging off.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is to just put a bead of hot glue along the top of the dowel. Let it dry, and it will provide enough friction to keep the ties in place. You may experiment with the amount of glue needed, as several small dots might be better than a single long bead.

Comment: Or bathroom sealant (silicone). Perhaps cut a groove in the top (as it's going to be used) and overfill that so it's more even and has more contact with the wood.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to one end of the tube, put some clear heatshrink on it. The stuff that shrinks 3:1 would do it. Try http://www.heatshrink.com/ - No connection, just a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't intended for clothing, I'd suggest sandpaper or stair-tred grip tape -- but those are too aggressive for this application. (Great for jigs, though )